# Creating a function with unknown number of inputs

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a VBA-function in Excel where the number of inputs are unknown.
The inputs are all going to be numbers.
I've found information about Paramarray, but don't know it thats a good choice, and I am not able to make it work.

Comment: I would firstly suggest you to forget about "I am not able to make it work" and try focusing on what you really want to accomplish. Can you better explain what you really want to do? Eventually, present some relevant pictures with what you have versus what would you like to obtain. Besides that, a piece of code made by your own, or collected from the net, will also help...

Comment: *I've found information about Paramarray, but don't know it thats a good choice* But you don't have another choice 

Answer (score 4):

You stated that

> I am not able to make it work.

However, you:

- Have not posted the problematic code
- have not posted your inputs
- have not posted your expected results
- have not posted your actual results

Given this lack of information, it is difficult to pinpoint your specific problem(s).  Here is an example of a working function with variable number of inputs.  Its purpose is to display for debugging, the values of several variables:

```
Public Function Displayy(ParamArray s()) As String
    Dim i As Long

    Displayy = CStr(s(0))
    If UBound(s) = 0 Then Exit Function
    For i = 1 To UBound(s)
        Displayy = Displayy & vbCrLf & CStr(s(i))
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your are building function, I am assuming the numbers are placed in Excel range (Example: `A1: A10`)

So you can use range as argument

```
Function YourFunctionName(rng as Range) as integer/Float/....etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use variant. It can be range or array of numbers.

```
Public Function DisplayZ(Inputs As Variant) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In Inputs
        DisplayZ = DisplayZ & vbCrLf & v
    Next v
End Function
```